# How to re-enter to docker containter prompt after exiting

Tags: linux, docker, unix

I'm running docker following [this procedure](https://hub.docker.com/r/epgg/eg/):

```
    $ sudo service docker start
    $ docker pull epgg/eg
    $ docker run -p 8081:80 --name eg -it epgg/eg bash
    root@35f54d7d290f:~#
```

Notice at the last step it creates a root prompt `root@35f54d7d290f:~#`.
When I do

```
 root@35f54d7d290f:~# exit
 exit
```

The docker process end and the Apache inside the container is dead.
How can I exit the container safely, and how can I re-enter the docker
container prompt back.

Answer (score 4):

Since the purpose of any container is to launch/run any process/processes, the container stops/exits when that process is finished. So to keep running the container in the background, it must have an active process inside it.

1. You can use **-d** shorthand while running the container to detach
   the container from the terminal like this:

   ```
   docker run -d -it --name {container_name} {image}:{tag}
   ```

   But this doesn't guarantee to run any process actively in the
   background, so even in this case container will stop when the
   process comes to an end.
2. To run the apache server actively in the background you need to use 
   **-DFOREGROUND** flag while starting the container:

   ```
   /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND     (for centOS/RHEL)
   ```

   This will run your apache service in background.
3. In other cases, to keep your services running in the detached mode
   simply pass on the `/bin/bash` command, this will keep the bash
   shell active in the background.

   ```
   docker run -d -it --name {container_name} {image}:{tag} /bin/bash
   ```

Anyway, to come outside the running container without exiting the container and the process, simply press: **Ctrl+P+Q**.

To attach container again to the terminal use this:

```
docker attach {container_name}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run following command it performs 2 operations.

```
$ docker run -p 8081:80 --name eg -it epgg/eg bash
```

- It creates a container named **eg**
- It has only one purpose/process **bash** that you have overridden using cmd parameter.

  - That means when bash shell is over/complete/**exit** container has no objective to run & hence your docker container will also entered into **stopped** stage.

Ideally you should create a container to run apache-server as the main process (either by default entry-point or cmd).

```
$ docker run -p 8081:80 --name eg -d epgg/eg
```

And then using following command you can enter inside the running container.

```
$ docker exec -it eg bash
```

here name of your container is eg
(Note since you already have a container named "eg" you may want to remove it first)

```
$ docker rm -f eg
```

Comment: I tried `docker run -p 8081:80 --name eg -d epgg/eg` successfully. But when I tried `docker exec -it eg bash` it gave me `Error response from daemon: Container 89d4da88e9ab90d8de9668956b0f4dee1aef21e1a285972e3e0f05519c665f19 is not running`